# AWK compare two columns in two seperate files

Tags: linux, bash, awk, comparison, data-analysis

I would like to compare two files and do something like this: if the 5th column in the first file is equal to the 5th column in the second file, I would like to print the whole line from the first file. Is that possible? I searched for the issue but was unable to find a solution :(

The files are separated by tabulators and I tried something like this:

```
zcat file1.txt.gz file2.txt.gz | awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$5];next}$5 in a {print $0}'
```

Did anybody tried to do a similar thing? :)

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: please provide a [mcve] !

Comment: Do those fields have to be on the same line ? Can you give a brief example of the input files and the output you expect ?

Comment: With your use of `zcat`, it's impossible to separate file1 from file2 -- you just have a single stream of lines, and `NR==FNR` is always true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your script is fine, but you need to provide each file individually to awk and in reverse order.

```
$ cat file1.txt
a b c d 100
x y z w 200
p q r s 300
1 2 3 4 400

$ cat file2.txt
. . . . 200
. . . . 400

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$5];next} $5 in a {print $0}' file2.txt file1.txt
x y z w 200
1 2 3 4 400
```

**EDIT**:

As pointed out in the comments, the generic solution above can be improved and tailored to OP's situation of starting with compressed tab-separated files:

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$5];next} $5 in a' <(zcat file2.txt) <(zcat file1.txt)
x y z w 200
1 2 3 4 400
```

**Explanation**:

**NR** is the number of the current record being processed and **FNR** is the number
of the current record *within its file* . Thus `NR == FNR` is only
true when awk is processing the first file given to it (which in our case is file2.txt).

`a[$5]` adds the value of the 5th column as an index to the array `a`. Arrays in awk are associative arrays, but often you don't care about associating a value and just want to make a nice collection of things. This is a
pithy way to make a collection of all the values we've seen in 5th column of the
first file. The `next` statement, which follows, says to immediately get the next
available record without looking at any anymore statements in the awk program.

Summarizing the above, this line says "If you're reading the first file (file2.txt),
save the value of column 5 in the array called `a` and move on to the record without
continuing with the rest of the awk program."

```
NR == FNR { a[$5]; next }
```

Hopefully it's clear from the above that the only way we can past that first line of
the awk program is if we are reading the second file (file1.txt in our case).

`$5 in a` evaluates to true if the value of the 5th column occurs as an index in
the `a` array. In other words, it is true for every record in file1.txt whose 5th
column we saw as a value in the 5th column of file2.txt.

In awk, when the pattern portion evaluates to true, the accompanying action is
invoked. When there's no action given, as below, the default action is triggered
instead, which is to simply print the current record. Thus, by just saying
`$5 in a`, we are telling awk to print all the records in file1.txt whose 5th
column also occurs in file2.txt, which of course was the given requirement.

```
$5 in a
```

Comment: Since they are compressed file you may want to say `awk '...' <(zcat file2) <(zcat file1)`. Also, `{print $0}` is redundant here, `$5 in a` suffices.

Comment: Thanks as always @fedorqui, incorporated!

Comment: @jas : Please could you explain what `$5 in a` does?

Comment: Hi @sjsam, your question inspired me to write way too much by way of explaining the one-liner. For your particular question, the Readers Digest version is _`$5 in a` evaluates to true if the value of the 5th column occurs as an index in the array `a`_.

Comment: What is not clear is whether the OP wishes to compare the records in order.

Comment: why the `-F '\t'`  by default it takes tab and white space as separator ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu, the `-F'\t'` was only because OP said their file was tab-separated. I suppose it's possible that some fields could contain spaces within them (we haven't seen sample data) in which case the default wouldn't be appropriate.